# Azure: Why do I get 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a node.js API to Azure Web Apps via BitBucket. The process was working just fine until we added a private repo that needs to be compiled after it's installed.

I'm using the postinstall-build npm package to run the babel-cli post-install to compile our es2015 code to es5 in a private npm repo.

This works perfectly on my dev machine, but Azure doesn't recognize npm for some goofy reason, even though it's literally installing other packages.

Here's part of the logs:

```
...    
> dtrace-provider@0.6.0 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\dtrace-provider
    > node scripts/install.js


    > js-models@0.0.2 postinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\private-repo
    > postinstall-build lib 'npm run compile'

    { [Error: Command failed: 'npm
    ''npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null, cmd: '\'npm' }
    787-api@0.0.1 D:\home\site\wwwroot
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
...
```

And here is the "postinstall" script from package.json

```
"postinstall": "postinstall-build lib 'npm run compile'"
```

and the "compile" script:

```
"compile": "babel --presets es2015,stage-0 --plugins add-module-exports -d lib/ src/",
```

So the fact that we're even getting to the point of the "postinstall" script running tells me that npm is definitely there and doing stuff, but for some reason when the "postinstall" script runs it must be executed in a different shell or something.

Has anyone else encountered this and is there a way around it?

Comment: would it help if you specify the full path of npm? you can get all supported version of npm from  ```D:\Program Files (x86)\npm```

Comment: I'll give this a try...it makes sense. Is this the correct path to npm on an Azure Web App?

Comment: that is the folder, under it there is a list of supported NPM. go to http://{yourname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, and navigate to it, you will see all of them.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the issue

Comment: I didn't @JohnKalberer sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

For installing node module from private repository, you can try to set up an SSH `deploy key` on BitBucket, please follow the section [`For private repos, set up a deploy key`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#for-private-repos-set-up-a-deploy-key) of Kudu Wiki for continuous deployment and see the figure for using deployment keys on BitBucket.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did add the SSH key which allowed me to pull the repo but the problem is after the repo is installed and the postinstall script runs

Answer (score -1):

This seems related to this other question. My problem was resolved with the solution described here:
[LUIS-app: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, when trying to install "Kudu Sync"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416032/luis-app-npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-when-tryin/51447079)