# LUIS-app: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, when trying to install "Kudu Sync"

Tags: azure, npm, azure-language-understanding

I have followed the [tutorial to integrate LUIS and QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis) to create a LUIS app. When I got to the [final step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis#build-the-bot) and tried to build the app, I got the error message

```
\> \build.cmd 
    Installing Kudu Sync 
    An error has occurred during web
    site deployment. 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external 
    command, operable program or batch file.
```

Apparently, npm is missing on the build server. How can that be and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try running build from the console to see if that resolves this issue.

1. First, from your App Service Editor click on your bot name at the top and select Open Kudu Console:

[image: Open Kudu Console]

2. this will open the diagnostic console in a new tab. Enter `cd site\wwwroot && build.cmd`

Hopefully that works!

Comment: When I tried it again a few days later, the problem was gone. Seems to have been a temporary glitch , which is a bit worrying...